# There exists a continuous inverse of $(\text{id}-A)$ in the set $(\text{id}-A)(X)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, inverse, compact-operators

**Exercise :**

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A \in \mathcal{L}_c(X)$ (means that $A$ is a compact operator). Suppose that $(\text{id}-A)$ is $"1-1"$. Show that the operator $(\text{id}-A)$ has a continuous inverse over the set $V=(\text{id}-A)(X)$.

**Question :**

As I fail to comprehend the question fully into functional analysis terms, how would one show that there exists a continuous inverse ? What is sufficient to prove that ?

Since $(\text{id}-A)$ is injective, there would exists an inverse if it was also surjective as well, but I can't seem to find a way around that. Also for the continuity, what's the catch ? Does showing that $(\text{id}-A)$ is an isometry has anything to do with that ?

Any hint on how to approach or elaboration will be the most appreciated since I cannot get a grasp on an intuition.

Comment: This depends a little bit on your background, e.g. do you know basic Fredholm theory?

Comment: @Klaus Thanks from replying. I am afraid that we have only mentioned what a Fredholm operator is and what its index is. After that, we have neither elaborated nor used it anywhere.

Comment: Basically you need that the index is invariant under compact perturbations. This would imply surjectivity.

Comment: @Klaus I am at loss on how to elaborate over that, literally never used any of these. What about continuity ? Anyway, I would be very welcome if you could elaborate.

Comment: The inverse of any bounded invertible operator is bounded again (bounded inverse theorem). Boundedness is equivalent to continuity.

Comment: @Klaus Okay, that's straightforward and sorry for foreseeing that with asking. But, regarding that the index is invariant, can you please elaborate ? I know that if a set is invariant under an operation, this means that the operation on elements on the set falls back into it. Regarding what you mentioned, how would one proceed ?

Comment: It means that the index of $\text{id}-A$ is equal to the index of $\text{id}$, which is $0$. Therefore, if $\text{id}-A$ is injective, it is also surjective.